# Insert with cascade Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes with a relation of `@OneToMany`.

The class `Player`:

I have a `List` of items and I mapped like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="player", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<InventoryItem> inventory;
```

And in my class `InventoryItem`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_player")
private Player player;
```

This is my `InventoryItem` table:

[image]

When i save a `Player`, i also want to save the `InventoryItem` i had inserted in the `inventory` `List` of the player, but it create the item in the table and set the `id_player` to `Null`

Comment: You set player in InventoryItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inventory item has a Player object member which is mapped by id_player and it is null so the id_player in the column is null. You need to set the Player= yourPlayer in the inventory object and it will fill the column in the database.